# removeFromParent action does not perform intended function

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a method that creates a line that is supposed to increase the score and that method is called in intervals and whenever there is two or more of the same line, whenever the Hero contacts the line closest to him, I run a removeFromParent Action and the line that is farthest away is removed instead. However the problem does not occur when the first line in contacted before other lines are generated. How can I rectify this? The lines are connected to platforms in the middle.

**platformGenerationMethod**

```
-(void)createPlatform {
    switch (arc4random_uniform(2)) {
    case (0):
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"shortPlatform3"];
        platformCount ++;
        NSLog(@"%li", (long)platformCount);
        break;
    case (1):
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"shortPlatform3"];
        platformCount ++;
        NSLog(@"%li",(long)platformCount);
        break;
    case (2):
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"shortPlatform3"];
        platformCount ++;
        NSLog(@"%li", (long)platformCount);
    default:
        break;
    }
    variaPlatform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:objectTexture];
    variaPlatform.name = @"variaPlatform";
    variaPlatform.zPosition = 2;
    variaPlatform.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:variaPlatform.size];
    variaPlatform.physicsBody.friction = 1;
    variaPlatform.physicsBody.linearDamping = 1;
    variaPlatform.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = fPlatformCategory;
    variaPlatform.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = fPlayerCategory | fEnemyCategory;
    variaPlatform.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = fPlayerCategory | fEnemyCategory;
    variaPlatform.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    variaPlatform.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    variaPlatform.position = CGPointMake(700, variaPlatform.position.y - 129);

    scoreLine = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(0.5, 700)];
    scoreLine.hidden = NO;
    scoreLine.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    scoreLine.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:scoreLine.size];
    scoreLine.position = CGPointMake(variaPlatform.position.x, variaPlatform.position.y/2);
    scoreLine.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = fScoreCategory;
    scoreLine.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = fPlayerCategory;
    scoreLine.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;

    [self addChild:scoreLine];
    [self addChild:variaPlatform];
    [self connectNode1:variaPlatform toNode2:scoreLine];
    [variaPlatform runAction:variaActions];
}
```

**didBeginContact**

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {

    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }

    if (((firstBody.categoryBitMask & fPlayerCategory) !=0) && ((secondBody.categoryBitMask & fScoreCategory) != 0))
    {
        NSLog(@"score");
        currentScore++;
        [scoreLine runAction:removeFromParent];
        [currentScoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)currentScore]];
    }
}
```

Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried debugging ?

Comment: @prototypical I actually don't know how to debug. The options are eluding me as to what they actually do.

Comment: You need to learn, because that is what programmers do :) The bugs are eluding you at the moment, and taking initiative to learn how to use the debugger is the right choice.

Comment: @prototypical I'll learn, but could you also guide me the way to start learning how to debug?

Comment: Google "Xcode Debugger Tutorial" - the internets are amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should allow you to remove the correct score node...

```
// Returns a node that matches the specified category or nil
static inline SKSpriteNode *nodeFromBody(SKPhysicsBody *body1,
                                       SKPhysicsBody *body2,
                                       uint32_t category) {
    SKSpriteNode *node = nil;
    if (body1.categoryBitMask & category) {
        node = (SKSpriteNode *)body1.node;
    }
    else if (body2.categoryBitMask & category) {
        node = (SKSpriteNode *)body2.node;
    }
    return node;
}

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;
    SKSpriteNode *player = nil;
    SKSpriteNode *score = nil;
    SKSpriteNode *enemy = nil;

    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;

    player = nodeFromBody(firstBody, secondBody, fPlayerCategory);
    score = nodeFromBody(firstBody, secondBody, fScoreCategory);
    enemy = nodeFromBody(firstBody, secondBody, fEnemyCategory);

    // Test for contact between nodes
    if (player) {
        if (score) {
            NSLog(@"score");
            currentScore++;
            // remove the node that made contact with player
            [score runAction:removeFromParent];
            [currentScoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)currentScore]];
        }
        else if (enemy) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you also explain what made mine incorrect and what you did to rectify that? I like to learn as I go.

Comment: scoreLine was likely not the node that made contact with the player node (check the code that selects scoreLine to see why). My code determines which nodes collided directly from the contact object, so the correct score node is removed from the scene.